# Javascript ReGEX for JSON

Tags: json

This is all so confusing, I've seen so many examples of how to do different things and cannot seem to find a valid example for what I am trying to do.

I'm using the YQL for the stock quotes only to get just the major indexes, DOW S&P 500 and NASDAQ.

The project is getting the data and working, but I need to determine if the stock value is returning +  or - (up or down).

if the market is up or flat, I want to add a CSS class to set it to green, if it is down, I want to set a CSS to red.

One other issue, this only seems to work when I place the function between the head and body, not in the head, not in the body.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function stock_quotes(obj)
{
    var items = obj.query.results.quote;
    var output = '';
    var num_quotes = items.length;
    items[0].symbol = "DOW ";
    items[1].symbol = "NASDAQ ";
    items[2].symbol = "S&P 500 ";
    //var posquote = {"\d\.?\d{0,9}\.\d{0,9}\s\+"};
    //var negquote = {"\d\.?\d{0,9}\.\d{0,9}\s\-"};
    for (var i = 0; i < num_quotes; i++) {
        var link = items[i].url;
        var symbl = items[i].symbol;
        var Change_PercentChange = items[i].Change_PercentChange;
        var LastTradePriceOnly = items[i].LastTradePriceOnly;
        output += "<table><tr><td>" + "<a href='" + link + "'>" + symbl + "</a>" + LastTradePriceOnly + " " + Change_PercentChange  + "</td></tr></table>";
    }
    // Place news stories in div tag  
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;  
}
```

This is the HTML with the query

```
<div id='results'></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22DOW%22%2C%22%5EIXIC%22%2C%22%5EGSPC%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=stock_quotes'></script>
```

Ideally I'd like to predefine the html elements which would make it easier to set the css class but one headache at a time.

Comment: This is not a job for regex, it's a job for `parseFloat` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this seemed to work just fine

```
 var match_nas_neg = nas_result.match(/\-/);
```